# How do I create a customised table list of a custom post type (in the admin area)?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, post-meta

I have created a custom post type, it has five (yes, really) taxonomies. It is designed to be used exclusively by the plugin and not displayed to end-users. If this was a regular post, we would have the "all posts" view in the admin area. I need something like that for my custom type (but without edit options and other changes) mostly for use by site owner and super admin.

I am aware of the possibility of extending WP_List_Table but I am unsure if this is the best approach.

What is the "correct" way to show this table of information, have it only link to an admin view of the item (non-editable - that's most important - no editing should happen) and generally customise the heck out of the table? (For example, I want to show the count of taxonomy entries across all five as a sortable column, show icons for various potential/optional metadata, and display a few other bits of meta-data).

Comment: You can do this via code, but if you're looking for something quick I'd recommend the Admin Columns plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

Comment: I certainly need to do it by code. This is quite a complex and niche plugin that needs to do the hard work for itself if possible.